# Incorrect answer in a questions linked to 'Sequential Experiments in Probability' due to diff. approach

Tags: probability, permutations, bayes-theorem

Two white pawns are placed at random on the third row of a chessboard. Assume that the chessboard is oriented in such a way that the allowable moves for the pawn are in the fourth row (in other words the bottom right extreme square is white). A black knight is placed at random on the fourth row. Assume that the only other pieces on the board are the two kings and that they occupy the first and last rows.

Compute:the probability that the knight can be captured in the next
move, if it is white’s turn;

My Approach:- the pawns can either be placed as:- (a) both not in corners
(b) one in corner and the other not in corner
(c) both in corners. Which will allow 4,3 and 2 places respectively for the knights to be positioned in order to be eliminated. the answer in that case would be (6/8)*(5/7)*(4/8)+(6/8)*(2/8)*(3/8)*2+(2/8)*(1/7)*(2/8) which is not equal to  the answer which is 23/56, How have I erred?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It's much easier to think about where the knight can go.  If the knight is one of the ends (a $\frac 28$ event) then there is only square to attack from (hence a $\frac 28$ chance he is threatened).  If the knight is not on an edge there are two places to attack from and the chance that both are empty is $\frac 68\times \frac 57$. Hence the chance that he is threatened is $1-\frac 68\times \frac 57$.  combining these cases gives $\frac {23}{56}$ as desired.

Comment: Should say, I can't really follow what you wrote.  If you insist on starting with the pawn placement then you have to separate out the cases in which the two pawns threaten a common square.  The knight centered approach is easier.

Comment: ok, thanks @lulu

Comment: Attempting to get something like your expression placing the knight (not edge or edge) then one pawn (attacking the knight or not) and then if needed the second pawn, I got $\frac68\left(\frac28+\frac68\times \frac27\right) +\frac28\left( \frac18+\frac78\times\frac17\right) =\frac{23}{56}$

Comment: ok, thanks @Henry !

Comment: @MisterMister'sBrokenWings Error in your considerations is your thought that knight has only 3 or 2 places to be positioned if one pawn is in the corner. Number of places for knight will depend on distance between pawns.

Comment: I didn't think of that, thanks @IvanKaznacheyeu